# soffice command don't work libreoffice4

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, libreoffice, soffice

When i had libreoffice3 it worked well , but when i unistall this version with this commande

```
sudo apt-get remove libreoffice-core

sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice-cor
```

And i download  LibreOffice_4.3.0_Linux_x86-64_deb.tar.gz
And installed them  by

```
 sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

'soffice' doesn't work any help please

Comment: Ubuntu specific, so should be moved to the Ubuntu SE Site, which is not in the provided list. Super User is applicable but not the most likely to address this issue as distro specific advice should be provided.

Comment: I think the upstream debs don't install into the PATH. Have a look into /opt/../program and start soffice from there.